# Compare two arrays in a easy way using Perl

Tags: perl, cgi

Is there any easy way to compare two string arrays in Perl?

```
@array1  = (value1, value2, value3...);
@array2  = (value1, value3, value4...);
```

I need the comparison like below for "N" Number of values,

```
value1 eq value1 
value2 eq value3
value3 eq value4
```

Please suggest me is there any module to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm... a module to compare arrays, you say. How about [Array::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Compare)?

```
use Array::Compare;

my $compare = Array::Compare->new;

my @array1  = (value1, value2, value3...);
my @array2  = (value1, value3, value4...);

if ($compare->compare(\@array1, \@array2)) {
  say "Arrays are the same";
} else {
  say "Arrays are different";
}
```

But you can also use the smart match operator.

```
if (@array1 ~~ @array2) {
  say "Arrays are the same";
} else {
  say "Arrays are different";
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Just a minor correction. A closing parentheses is needed on the line containing the if statement (e.g. `if ($compare->compare(\@array1, \@array2)) {`

Answer (score 4):

You can compare sizes of both arrays (`@a1 == @a2` in scalar context), and then compare size of `@a1` array with size of list of indices which correspond to equal strings in both arrays (`grep $a1[$_] eq $a2[$_], 0..$#a1`),

```
if (@a1 == @a2 and @a1 == grep $a1[$_] eq $a2[$_], 0..$#a1) { print "equal arrays\n" }
```

More performance oriented version (doesn't go through all elements if not necessary),

```
use List::Util 'all';

if (@a1 == @a2 and all{ $a1[$_] eq $a2[$_] } 0..$#a1) { print "equal arrays\n" }
```

Comment: I didn't like your first solution because it compared every item in both arrays but you solved that problem with your second solution so this answer gets my vote as the best so far.

Answer (score 3):

Perl already has some parts for a solution to any list operations.

See [**`List::Util`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util) and [**`List::MoreUtils`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils).

```
my $arrays_are_equal
    = !List::Util::pairfirst { $a ne $b }      # first case where $a != $b
      List::MoreUtils::zip( @array1, @array2 ) 
    ;
```

For this application, see [**`List::Util::pairfirst`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util#pairfirst) and [**`List::MoreUtils::zip`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils#zip)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This task is simple enough that I wouldn't necessarily want to use a CPAN module. Instead, I would likely write my own comparison subroutine and put it in my own utility module. Here is one implementation that will compare two arrays containing strings and/or integers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1  = (1..10, 'string');
my @array2  = (1..10, 'string');

my $is_same = is_same(\@array1, \@array2);

print "is_same: $is_same\n";

sub is_same {
  my($array1, $array2) = @_;

  # immediately return false if the two arrays are not the same length
  return 0 if scalar(@$array1) != scalar(@$array2);

  # turn off warning about comparing uninitialized (undef) string values
  # (limited in scope to just this sub)
  no warnings;

  for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#$array1; $i++) {
    if ($array1->[$i] ne $array2->[$i]) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  return 1;
}
```